# How would I express conditional summation.

Tags: functions

I was hoping the experts here could help me out. I need to express conditional summation.
Let me give you guys an example. Suppose I have a timeline like this:

[image: timeline]

Each value on the time-line in the above image represents a value in hours and the red box around the values shows that an event had occurred at that time. This is all well and good however i need a way to modify the above expression so that it considers only those values that have a red box around them and ignores the rest for example:

[image: timeline example]

Correction in the image (its suppose to be 5-3 sorry about that)

Any suggestions on how i could do that would be appreciated or how the expression should look like...

Comment: Define another function, say f(t) = 1 when t has a box around it; 0 otherwise.

Comment: @TheChaz Could you explain that a bit in detail

Comment: Sorry I was on my phone... Why not just take $(8 - 3)$, the difference of the first and last numbers with boxes around them?

Comment: @TheChaz hmm.. That definitely makes sense.. I'll look into and get back here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of numbers with red boxes around them.

Then you want something like $\displaystyle\sum_{a\in S} t_a - t_{a+1}$

This sort of symbol is well-defined for finite sets.  Also, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n$ could be rewritten as $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in N}$ where $N=\{0,\dots,n\}$